# nginx 403 external image error

Tags: apache, nginx, http-status-code-403

I have just setup a nginx server for the first time. And I cannot load external images on my website.

I am trying to load resources from "ia.media-imdb.com" and receiving a 403 forbidden error. I believe it's likely this error message is due to the source server preventing the type of hotlinking I'm attempting to do, which can easily be done through the web server configuration right.
But I still haven't figured out what to change in the configuration.
I have granted 755 access to almost all the files and folder

This is my site conf in nginx/sites_availible/conf

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name _;
location  /{
    proxy_pass http://178.62.31.49:4000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    allow all;
}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction or help me solve this, that would be great.

Comment: For example I can not access using curl
curl --referer http://178.62.31.49 http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTY0NjI0ODY3NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNDg5MDU1MQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg